# Run multi sql command in the same zeppelin paragraph

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Hello I have 3 tmpViews I want to show these views in the same zeppelin scatter dashboard I m using Spark interpreter I want to get each view with a color (i.e point of the same view have the same color)
         I tried

```
     %spark
     z.show(sql("select valrx, valry from MemArb "))
     z.show(sql("select valx , valry  from VoisArb "))
     z.show(sql("select valrx , valry from VoisArb2 "))
```

but it gives me only the first view

is there any solution?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Zeppelin 08.0 support to show multiple dataframe in one paragraph, but regarding different colors, it is not supported yet. I'm afraid you need to use other solutions, like using python plot libraries.

Comment: Thank u for your response, I can't change the default colors from " \zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all\webapps\webapp\scripts"?

Answer (score 0):

You can print result to [table display system](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/display_system/basic.html#table).

Begin with '%table ' and then print to csv with separator equals '\t'